# How to make Treeview recursive?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, recursion, treeview

I have the following code to populate data in Treeview. How can I make it recursive so that I will have multiple layers ?
Currently it is shown as follows but I would like to show it as three layers instead.

[Here is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JGG6.png)

But I am looking for, say, for  `bomitem= '500101' && bomrev='B'`

```
      500101
       ----100200
       ----300255
            ----100214


 treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BOMDETAIL ORDER BY partId", cn);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["bomItem"].ToString());
                    node.Nodes.Add(dr["partId"].ToString());
                    //node.Nodes.Add(dr["qty"].ToString());
                    node.Nodes.Add(dr["bomRev"].ToString());
                    treeView2.Nodes.Add(node);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4jRV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BOMDETAIL ORDER BY partId", cn);
      try
      {
          SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          SomeFun(dr, treeView2);
      }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }    
}

private void SomeFun(SqlDataReader dr, TreeView treeView2)
{
    if(dr.Read())
    {
       TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["bomItem"].ToString());
       node.Nodes.Add(dr["partId"].ToString();
       node.Nodes.Add(dr["bomRev"].ToString());
       treeView2.Nodes.Add(node);
       SomeFun(dr, treeView2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. how can i call these when button onclick() event

Comment: you code also display the same  I want to see  `300255 and 100200` under `500101` and under `300255->100214`

Comment: Are 300255 and 100200 bomRev?

Comment: 300255 and 100200 are partId the bomRev's are A and B. `bomRev and bomItem` are the PK's

Comment: You need to provide what columns the query returns and tell how each column are related

Comment: Just `bomItem` and `partId` on the tree that i like to see. did i answer your question?

Comment: I understand 500101 is bomItem.  under this you want 300255 and 100200 which are partId. Where you want to place the bomRevs?

Comment: yes under 500101--> 300255 and 100200 , and under  300255 -->100214 and I don't want to show bomRev on the Tree just partIds under bomItem

Comment: What is 100214? do you have another level below partId?

Comment: It is child /component of partId 300255

Comment: What is the corresponding column in the database table, because from data reader i can get this only from its column name?

Comment: `partId`. here i added a picture at the bottom of my question or you can find it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4jRV.png

Comment: I think You have a self-referential integrity in your table.. You could have told that upfront. Thats what i was asking for relationship between the columns you have.

Comment: Vinoth all are on the single table i didn't use foreign key here or any field outside these table.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion 
1. Create the new class called as BOMDETAIL and create the property of the class  how many columns you have in table each have one property like bomItem, partId  etc... 
2. create the collection for that class ex List. and create the object for BOMDETAIL class and assign value to each property from dr variable inside of while loop each BOMDETAIL class obect add the List.

ex:  List lstBom = new List
           while(dr.Read())

```
               BOMDETAIL bom= new BOMDETAIL();
                bom.bomItem = dr["bomItem"].ToString();
                    ....
               lstBom.add(b);
```

3. Now you can given the order what ever you want like recursive in the lstBom and assign to the treeview Node Collection object or ItemSource.

Thanks for your question